# How to boot OpenWRT FROM PXE?

Tags: openwrt, initrd, pxe

I have downloaded OpenWRT files for PC from [OpenWRT site](https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.4/targets/x86/64/). I have installed `DHCP` and `TFTP` (in my LAN) and can boot (other) kernels from them.

Now I want to boot these OpenWRT files.

I wrote in PXE config

```
DEFAULT minimallinux
  SAY Now booting Minimal Linux...

LABEL minimallinux
MENU LABEL Minimal Linux
KERNEL vmlinuz
INITRD rootfs-squashfs.img.gz
```

It boots, loads kernel, then loads image, then starts boot printouts and finaly crashes with kernel panic and reboots

```
VFS:Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error-6
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown un-blokc(0,0)
```

I also tried

```
KERNEL vmlinuz
APPEND initrd=rootfs-squashfs.img.gz boot=live toram=rootfs-squashfs.img.gz
```

and some other combinations but failed.

Any hints appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

try the generic-rootfs.tar.gz ( https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.4/targets/x86/64/openwrt-18.06.4-x86-64-generic-rootfs.tar.gz )

this works for me with

```
LABEL openwrt
    KERNEL openwrt/openwrt-x86-64-generic-vmlinuz
    APPEND initrd=openwrt/openwrt-x86-64-generic-Generic-rootfs.tar.gz
```

(adapt the filenames)